# How to use a variable in a new activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I added a variable that pass form the first activity to the second one.
I want to use the info that has accepted from the first activity, at the new activity, and will save it on new double variable, display it as permanent on a textView.
Now, it appears only when I am clicking on the regular button that start the new activity.

As first step, I guess, I need to remove - "startActivity(intent1);".
How should I move on from here?

Java code:
First Activity (Name : settings.java)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
}
    public void onClick (View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(settings.this, WaitressRecord.class);
    startActivity(intent);


}


protected void onClickWait (View v) {

    //--- Casting & Converting EditText "etSalaryWaitress" to Double "doubleSW".
    btnWaitress =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWaitress);
    etSalaryWaitress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSalaryWaitress);
    doubleSW = Double.parseDouble(etSalaryWaitress.getText().toString());
    //---Casting Radio Button(s).
    rbPercentage = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbPercentage);
    rbShekel = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbShekel);


    if (doubleSW < 100 ) {
        if (rbPercentage.isChecked()) {
            HafrashaP = 1 - (doubleSW / 100.0);
            strHafPer = String.valueOf(HafrashaP);
            Toast.makeText(settings.this, strHafPer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // start the SecondActivity
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, WaitressRecord.class);
            intent1.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strHafPer);
            startActivity(intent1);
        } else if (rbShekel.isChecked()) {
            HafrashaS = -doubleSW;
            strHafShek = String.valueOf(HafrashaS);
            Toast.makeText(settings.this, strHafShek, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(settings.this, "לא הוזנה סוג ההפרשה", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(settings.this, "מספר שגוי", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

New Activity: (Name : WaitressRecord.java)

```
public class WaitressRecord extends AppCompatActivity {

    String strHafPer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_waitress_record);

        // get the text from MainActivity
        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        strHafPer = intent1.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

        // use the text in a TextView
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(strHafPer);
    }
}
```

Comment: "display it as permanent on a textView" do you want that info to persist somewhere, like on a SQLite database? and your onClickWait() doesn't seems to be used

Comment: I'm not using SQLite. I don't think I need to use it for couple of variables. or am I wrong? @AndrewChiLam

Comment: Explain what do you are trying to achieve by that  
"display it as permanent on a textView" . If you want text view to show a value when the activity is recreated, you need to persist it somewhere, let it be  savedInstanceState (screen rotation), sharedPreferences of a SQLite database.

Comment: Also, is onClickWait() being called at all? If your button is just using onClick(), nothing would happen because there is no extra passed in with the intent in the onClick().

Comment: the onClickWait() is used. it get data in form of double and this time I want to know how can I send it to another activity and save it there as a double

Comment: I'm still very confused as to what you are trying to achieve, just store it using sharedPreferences and let the second activity retrieve it. Activities flow are not for "save it there" operations, activities are for UI receiving user interactions.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //First Activity 
Intent intent= new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(VARIABLE_KEY, value);
intent.putExtras(mBundle);
  startActivity(intent);

 //on the second Acitivty 

 intent intent = getIntent();
 Bundle bundleExtra;
 //Null Checking
if (intent != null ) { 
bundleExtra = getIntent().getExtras();
// Be sure your check your "VARIABLE KEY SAME AS in THE FIRST ACTIVITY
String resultString = extras.getString("VARIABLE_KEY");
}
```

Comment: Should I just add it?  in onCreate?
and maybe  "Intent intent= new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);" [Row 2]
need to be Intent intent= new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

Comment: To change the Activity  you put it where you call startActivity(intent) 

To retrieve data  : you call it where you want . can be onCreate() .too